# How to add custom column in outlook while using DocumentItem

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing **VSTO** addin using `C#`.

[image]

Here, I have drag one file from my PC to outlook folder. It displays in *outlook* as show in picture.

Now I want to *add* one column in that folder.
I have done some code to *add* custom column in folder. It will display in picture. Column name is `ABCDEFGHI`.

I want to update the value of `ABCD.pdf` file property.

As per outlook `ABCD.pdf` is a `DocumentItem`. I want to add my custom property for that file, to display in view.

This is my sample code.

```
 UserProperties objUserProperties  = objItem.UserProperties;
 UserProperty objUserProperty = objUserProperties.Add("ABCDEFGHI", OlUserPropertyType.olText);
 objt.Value = "YYYY";
```

This will give me an *error*.

Error: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [UserProperties.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/userproperties-add-method-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method description in MSDN you can see the following description:

> You cannot add custom properties to Office document items such as Word, Excel, or PowerPoint files. You will receive an error when you try to programmatically add a user-defined field to a DocumentItem object.

Instead, I'd recommend creating any Outlook item and attaching a document to it. Following that way you will be able to customize the View by adding user properties as you need.